# Retrieving the Assembly for Dependancy-Injection

Tags: visual-studio, reflection, dependency-injection

The case is "simple". In my solution, I have two projects :
1- MasterProject
2- SneakyProject
3- SneakyInterface

SneakyProject classes implement the SneakyInterfaces. MasterProject refers SneakyInterface. In MasterProject, I instantiate some SneakyProject with some dependency injection / reflection. MasterProject gets the actual name of the assembly and the classes with a configuration file.

**The question is :** To get the SneakyProject assembly, I could use a post-build event to copy the assembly. I could also just create a reference to this project, or maybe something else. What would a best-practiser do? Why?

Comment: Why you don't want to add a static reference to the SneakyProject?

Comment: In the MasterProject's reference list you mean? I don't like the idea because it's not "true". What I mean is that one could, at any time, change SneakyProject for any assembly that implements ISneaky. Adding a reference to SneakyProject would, in a "philosophical" way mean that THIS version of THAT assembly is what should be used. So if want to use a new assembly and the former assembly is in the GAC and one forget to change the config file, it would still use the old assembly, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a post buid event, because this really has nothing to do with your application architecture.

Comment: Thanks. I went with a simple : copy /y "$(TargetPath)" "$(SolutionDir)\MasterProject\$(OutDir)" :-D